# Can not access to localhost from external ip

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

I would like access to my local tomcat admin from the external ip address.

By doing `http://192.168.1.4:8080/` (internal ip) request it works perfectly ( i see tomcat)

By doing `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`(internal ip) it works

By doing `http://151.48.112.116:80` (external ip address)  it works and goes on the Router administration

By doing `http://151.48.112.116:8080`  i get 404

i did the port forwarding on the  192.168.1.4  address

Screenshots of the router settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshots show an xbox, so I guess this question is "home related"

Comment: yes home related

Comment: why you put -1 damn what is the problem with my question ?

Comment: Your question is good but should not be asked on this website : I downvoted because the question is home related : http://serverfault.com/faq "and it is not about… Anything in a home setting"

Comment: i could have the same problem over my home .. what dose mean that ?

Comment: my home is an office too

Comment: Because you work at home, I upvoted your question

Comment: I do not think that saying "my home is a office too" qualifies. The problem is with the setting and with the equipment. This is a site for professional server and network administrators and the scope of the site fits very badly with home gear such as this one from netgear.

Comment: the answer was not so obvious, maybe the problem was not so trivial in spite of the equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is router specific you are in a dual NAT situation:

Excerpt stolen from [here](http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide/dnat_to_same_network.html)

> This problem occurs when machines on an internal LAN try to access a
>   server (let's say a web server) that is actually located on the same
>   LAN and NAT'ed through the firewall for external access. If internal
>   users access it by its external NATted address, then they send their
>   TCP packets through the firewall, which translates them and sends them
>   to the server on LAN. The server, however, replies back to the clients
>   directly because they are on the same network. Since the reply has
>   server's real address in the source, clients do not recognize it and
>   the connection cannot be established.

We would need to know router models to see if you can get round this. Since it's a home router there may be no way around it.

Comment: right answer ....

Comment: you are sure there is no way to round this ?? please

Comment: mine is D-link DSL-2740B

Comment: Just RTFM an no there is no way around it. It's no biggie though just use the internal IP inside and external IP outside,

Comment: there may not be on a locked down firmware such as this on linux, but on general purpose Linux and on IOS and JunOS you can fix this with nat. A way that may work with this particular platform is split DNS. Setup an internal dns that catches a call for a public dns domain and direct it to your internal ip. People from outside would use the "real" dns record of the domain, pointing to the public ip of the router.

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://151.48.112.116:8008` or changing the `External Port` to `8080`. Is that a typo?

Comment: i did http://151.48.112.116:8008 but dose not works as i said ..

Comment: Port 8080 isn't a typo, it is a commonly used substitute port especially on systems hosted by consumer ISP's preventing homeowners from becoming low bandwidth ecommerce sites for $40 home user rates.  But it is so commonly used that intruders hunt for it to when scarfing for web servers especially if they know that ISP on that address block filters 80. Sprint Mobile broadband is a good example, they filter HTTP/HTTPS but allow the HTTP protocol on high ports instead of just filtering inbound HTTP as a protocol on any port. Meaning a guy can host a web server from a moving car.

Comment: explain it please i don't get what to do....

Comment: On the screenshot 8008 is a typo .. yes.

Comment: uploaded new screenshot